# How to run a script in EXCEL?

Tags: excel

I have a huge file in Excel of 97.000 rows. The 97k rows represent the name of my files from my hard drive. My task is to delete all the old files. My Excel file has 2 columns. The first one is the name of the file and the second column is "Delete" and I have to write for each file a Yes or No (so I know if I have to delete it). I have never used a script in Excel before, so I kinda need some help. I need a script that will write Yes under the "Delete" column for each file that contains a year in the name of the file.

If this is not clear, I will try to explain it more. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far to solve the problem on your own? Perhaps you need a tutorial or two. Please understand that this platform is not a code-on-request-for-no-charge service. We are usually gladly helping, but you should invest some more time first. Perhaps you consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

### You don't need to run a script.

You can simply use the [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function.
And as a for the IF function, use a function like [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-leftb-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), [RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/right-rightb-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) or [MIDDLE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-function-2eba57be-0c05-4bdc-bf81-5ecf4421eb8a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to check if your format of year exists within the string in the name column. If it does, Assign the value of TRUE to the delete column.

[Copy](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218) the formula for all the rows and you have it.